# Wireshark: could "Follow TCP Stream" yield an empty window? or is it a bug?

Tags: linux, wireshark, tcp

I am capturing a pop3 netcat connection (port 110) using Wireshark, on Debian linux (Kali). After filtering packets with (tcp.port eq 110) I get few packets but once I R.Click on any and click "Follow TCP Stream" I get empty window!

My question, is this a bug? (I found some ppl reporting it as a bug) or is this possible based on some conditions??

I tried to run Wireshark to analyze the pcap file, with root user and with limited user and the result is the same.

On some other packets I still can get contents on the TCP Stream window though.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it could be a bug.  Alternatively, if no packets containing data (all packets are empty) are included in the TCP stream, you'll also get an empty window.

Comment: Even if you get an empty data window, you should be able to see the packets associated with the stream in the main window.